# Chromecast Custom Receiver JPG loading

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am not able to cast a simple JPG or PNG file to chromecast device.
I keep getting the error message

```
[cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error
```

I even tried it with Google's examples "sample_media_receiver.html" and "web_sender_tool.html", but without success.

Video files like MP4 or even HLS work fine, but not an simple image. Altough in the default receiver the images are working, but not in the custom receiver.

I tried with different values of metadata and without any metadata - nothing helps.

Here is the log of the chromecast console (with working MP4 and not working JPG):

```
### Application Loaded. Starting system. sample_media_receiver.html:605
 [  0.285s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Opening message bus websocket
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.297s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.369s] [goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.380s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel opened
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.393s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"type":"opened"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.408s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.410s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Underlying message bus is open
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.413s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"ready\",\"statusText\":\"Ready to play\",\"activeNamespaces\":[\"urn:x-cast:com.google.devrel.custom\",\"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media\"],\"version\":\"2.0.0\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\"}"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.421s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"startheartbeat\",\"maxInactivity\":6000}"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.440s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"applicationId\":\"XXXXXXX\",\"applicationName\":\"MDTest\",\"launchingSenderId\":\"8:client-68103\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\",\"sessionId\":\"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69\",\"type\":\"ready\",\"version\":\"1.0\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.443s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"applicationId":"XXXXXXXX","applicationName":"MDTest","launchingSenderId":"8:client-68103","messagesVersion":"1.0","sessionId":"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69","type":"ready","version":"1.0"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.446s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.448s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager system ready event [[object Object]]
 cast_receiver.js:19
### Cast Receiver Manager is READY:  sample_media_receiver.html:204
 [  0.567s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"senderId\":\"8:client-68103\",\"type\":\"senderconnected\",\"userAgent\":\"\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.570s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"senderId":"8:client-68103","type":"senderconnected","userAgent":""}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.572s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.574s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager sender connected event [8:client-68103]
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.576s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.devrel.custom, 8:client-68103]
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.578s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 8:client-68103]
 cast_receiver.js:19
### Cast Receiver Manager - Sender Connected :  sample_media_receiver.html:217
 [ 17.252s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"requestId\":28532030,\"sessionId\":\"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/video0.mp4\",\"streamType\":\"buffered\",\"contentType\":\"video/mp4\",\"metadata\":null,\"duration\":null,\"customData\":null},\"autoplay\":true,\"currentTime\":null,\"customData\":null}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"8:client-68103"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 17.255s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 8:client-68103]: {"type":"LOAD","requestId":28532030,"sessionId":"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69","media":{"contentId":"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/video0.mp4","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"video/mp4","metadata":null,"duration":null,"customData":null},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":null,"customData":null}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 17.258s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received [8:client-68103] {"type":"LOAD","requestId":28532030,"sessionId":"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69","media":{"contentId":"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/video0.mp4","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"video/mp4","metadata":null,"duration":null,"customData":null},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":null,"customData":null}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 17.259s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager load event
 cast_receiver.js:19
### Media Manager - LOAD: {"type":"load","B":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Qa":true,"data":{"requestId":28532030,"sessionId":"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69","media":{"contentId":"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/video0.mp4","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"video/mp4","metadata":null,"duration":null,"customData":null},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":null,"customData":null},"senderId":"8:client-68103"} sample_media_receiver.html:549
### Media Protocol Identified as mp4 sample_media_receiver.html:588
######### MEDIA ELEMENT LOAD START sample_media_receiver.html:121
 [ 18.270s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Metadata loaded
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 18.286s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 18.300s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"BUFFERING\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/video0.mp4\",\"streamType\":\"buffered\",\"contentType\":\"video/mp4\",\"metadata\":null,\"duration\":8.057324,\"customData\":null}}],\"requestId\":28532030}"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
######### MEDIA ELEMENT DATA LOADED sample_media_receiver.html:125
######### MEDIA ELEMENT CAN PLAY sample_media_receiver.html:129
######### MEDIA ELEMENT PLAYING sample_media_receiver.html:137
 [ 20.625s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Buffering state changed, isPlayerBuffering: false old time: 0.083322 current time: 1.125
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 20.627s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 20.630s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"PLAYING\",\"currentTime\":1.125,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":0}"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
######### MEDIA ELEMENT ENDED sample_media_receiver.html:133
### Media Manager - ENDED:  sample_media_receiver.html:347
 [ 27.445s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Resetting media element
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 27.579s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 27.581s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"IDLE\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"idleReason\":\"FINISHED\"}],\"requestId\":0}"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
######### MEDIA ELEMENT ABORT [object Event] sample_media_receiver.html:153
 [ 31.019s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"requestId\":28532031,\"sessionId\":\"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/myimage.jpg\",\"streamType\":\"buffered\",\"contentType\":\"image/jpg\",\"metadata\":null,\"duration\":null,\"customData\":null},\"autoplay\":true,\"currentTime\":null,\"customData\":null}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"8:client-68103"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 31.028s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 8:client-68103]: {"type":"LOAD","requestId":28532031,"sessionId":"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69","media":{"contentId":"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/myimage.jpg","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"image/jpg","metadata":null,"duration":null,"customData":null},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":null,"customData":null}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 31.031s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received [8:client-68103] {"type":"LOAD","requestId":28532031,"sessionId":"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69","media":{"contentId":"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/myimage.jpg","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"image/jpg","metadata":null,"duration":null,"customData":null},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":null,"customData":null}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 31.033s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager load event
 cast_receiver.js:19
### Media Manager - LOAD: {"type":"load","B":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Qa":true,"data":{"requestId":28532031,"sessionId":"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69","media":{"contentId":"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/myimage.jpg","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"image/jpg","metadata":null,"duration":null,"customData":null},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":null,"customData":null},"senderId":"8:client-68103"} sample_media_receiver.html:549
### Media Protocol Identified as jpg sample_media_receiver.html:588
######### MEDIA ELEMENT LOAD START sample_media_receiver.html:121
######### MEDIA ELEMENT ERROR [object Event] sample_media_receiver.html:149
 [ 31.293s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error
 cast_receiver.js:19
### Media Manager - LOAD METADATA ERROR: {"senderId":"8:client-68103","message":{"requestId":28532031,"sessionId":"2A80FF6F-F9B2-4D78-D99A-997CF6FC2F69","media":{"contentId":"http://192.168.0.103/~marco/cast/myimage.jpg","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"image/jpg","metadata":null,"duration":null,"customData":null},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":null,"customData":null}} sample_media_receiver.html:399
 [ 31.297s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Resetting media element
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 31.303s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 8:client-68103
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [ 31.305s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"8:client-68103","data":"{\"requestId\":28532031,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: more to mention: I also tried all values for stream-type "none", "buffered", "live", "unknown" - no result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "custom receiver", it means that you have written your own receiver. When doing that, did you add any `<img/>` tag for images and the associated logic to use that element for images? Sounds like you have not. The Styled and Default receivers do that so that is why you can see images when using those receivers.

Comment: that makes everything clear! Thank you!
I thought the custom receiver sample is already doing that...